# Remove the automatically selection of md-autocomplete in angular 4 material application

Tags: angular, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have an angular 4 application with material design. In this applicatino I open a dialog with a form inside. In this form, I have an autocomplete field in first position.
This is my html code :

```
<div class="containerDialog">
<h1 md-dialog-title>Add porject</h1>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput type="text" mdInput [mdAutocomplete]="project" placeholder="Selectionner un projet">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-autocomplete #project="mdAutocomplete">
            <md-option *ngFor="let project of projectsList" [value]="project.name">
                {{ project.name}}
            </md-option>
        </md-autocomplete>
    </div>
</form>
<div md-dialog-actions>
    <button md-button md-dialog-close="close">Cancel</button>
    <button md-button md-dialog-close="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

When I open the dialog, the autocomplete input is selected, so the list of `project.name` appears without click on the input.

So, do you know how I can do to don't have the input selected at the opening but just when I click on it ?

Comment: how are you sending input to the modal dialog?

Comment: You have `focus` on the input field on opening the dialog? And you don't wan't that?

Comment: Yes, it's that, I don't want focus on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some similar problem. For me adding `cdk-focus-region-start` to the container worked.

In your case try this:

```html
<div cdk-focus-region-start class="form-group">
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput type="text" mdInput [mdAutocomplete]="project" placeholder="Selectionner un projet">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-autocomplete #project="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let project of projectsList" [value]="project.name">
            {{ project.name}}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

If this does not work try adding `cdk-focus-region-start` to the parent `form` and remove it from the `div`.

Comment: 'cdk-focus-start' works but is deprecated. The new one is : 'cdk-focus-region-start'

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143052/how-to-manually-set-focus-on-mat-form-field-in-angular-6 @onetwo12